# angular2: how to manually add css files by condition to index.html?

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli, external

The below code is that define for style.

```
<!-- for mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/mobile.css">

<!-- for desktop -->    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/desktop.css">
```

I want to add above files to <head> in 'src/index.html' by condition.

How can I apply a css file for each device?

As you know, I can't use 'Conditional' code in 'index.html'.

Note that I will not use the method below.

```
// in angular-cli.json
"apps": [
    {
        "root": "src",
        "index": "index.html",
        "styles": [
            "/dist/css/mobile.css",
            "/dist/css/desktop.css"
        ]
    }
]


// in component.ts
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrl: '/dist/css/mobile.css'
})
```

I look forward to your advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To dynamically load or change your CSS, you can do the following:

1. In index.html:

   You will have a stylesheet link as follows:

   `<link id="theme" href="assets/light.css" rel="stylesheet" >`

   Note that there is "id" for the link element.
2. In your component you will have as follows:

   Import the DOCUMENT from platform-browser

   `import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";`

   then, in your action or on init you will change your css accordingly:

   `this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href','assets/dark.css');`

By default, you will load one CSS file.. lets say desktop.css. In your application's root component, you can look for the device or cookie or setup some conditions to change from desktop.css to mobile.css. Like you said, you will NOT use angular-cli.json to load your CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @nasangW if the answer helped you why didnt you mark it as the right answer to really help others looking for same answer to know that this is the right anwser ?

Comment: document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href','assets/dark.css');

Comment: DOCUMENT now is imported from @angular/common.
The above import statement is deprecated.