# Adding CSS style url based on condition/input property Angular 2+

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a component and it has used in 2 places in application, one for listing and and another in slider, only difference is in CSS, one has larger view and another has smaller and some other CSS changes.

So I am thinking to use same component at both places and use different external style, but for that I need to add CSS url in to Component decorator dynamically.

Is this possible? If yes how?

Comment: Please so your code where component used and also share component

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42824862/7561290) can help you much.

Comment: You could also have your component include all CSS, but only use the correct one depending on the context

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the directive [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) and [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

If you want to change a single css property, choose ngStyle like this:

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'font-size': styleExp}">...</some-element>
```

Your styleExp could be a conditional statement like

```
  isSmall ? 80% : 100%
```

If you want to apply a style class you need to use ngClass like this:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{boolExp ? 'first' :'second'}">...</some-element>    
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': boolExp }">...</some-element>
```

your boolExp has to return a boolean value. You can use different combinations for multiple classes.

Use the urls above for reference.

[Here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass) is another URL for learning purposes: