# import css based on condition in styles.css angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

How to import css based on condition like below,

Angular7

**In styles.css**

```
if (data === 'mobile') {
  @import './assets/css/common1.css'; 
} else {
  @import './assets/css/common2.css'; 
}
```

**My problem is:**

I have two modules which loads different application in my project.

```
{
  path : ''
  loadChildren: Module1
}

{
  path : 'ng7'
  loadChildren: Module2
}
```

Here, I want to use Module 1 - common1.css and Module 2 - common2.css

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824472/angular2-how-to-manually-add-css-files-by-condition-to-index-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: how to manually add css files by condition to index.html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824472/angular2-how-to-manually-add-css-files-by-condition-to-index-html)

Comment: No Alok Deshwal. I tried . But my problem is to add only one css based on condition.

Comment: Sceanrio:  module1 need to load common1.css and module2 need to load common2.css. These 2 different application in my project

Comment: If you are loading the modules dynamically, then add css files using "styleUrls" to the associated components of module.

Comment: Yes but, common css for that module which differs in my scenario.